# Geojson data does not render on Mapbox gl js (though it works on mapbox studio)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I am trying to load a geojson file as an overlay on mapbox. I suspect that it works on mapbox studio because it converts it to a vector tileset for me before it generates the overlay. How can I get this code to display the power grid network data i have here? It should be displaying over east Ireland.

```html
        <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <title>Add a GeoJSON polygon</title>
        <meta name='viewport' content='initial-scale=1,maximum-scale=1,user-scalable=no' />
        <script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
        <link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.45.0/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
        <style>
            body { margin:0; padding:0; }
            #map { position:absolute; top:0; bottom:0; width:100%; }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>

    <div id='map'></div>
    <script>
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnlhbmVuaWFuIiwiYSI6ImNqeG9reW0wbzA3ZmwzaHA3ZGRlNGJhY3UifQ.IkI_4dMSNOWgdm7d1ReS6A'';
    var map = new mapboxgl.Map({
        container: 'map',
        style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/satellite-v9',
        center: [-7.62, 53.3],
        zoom: 9
    });



    map.on('load', function () {

        map.addSource('scmpd-precinct-polygons', {
          type: 'geojson',
          data: 'http://www.tilix.uk.s3.amazonaws.com/enian/posm-data/DI/DIct.geojson'
        });

        map.addLayer({
            'id': 'precinct-layer',
            'type': 'line',
            'source': 'scmpd-precinct-polygons',
            'layout': {},
            'paint': {
                'fill-color': '#088',
                'fill-opacity': 0.8
            }
        });
    });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a syntax error. Make sure your quotation marks are balanced :)

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnlhbmVuaWFuIiwiYSI6ImNqeG9reW0wbzA3ZmwzaHA3ZGRlNGJhY3UifQ.IkI_4dMSNOWgdm7d1ReS6A'';
```

Should be:

```
    mapboxgl.accessToken = 'pk.eyJ1IjoicnlhbmVuaWFuIiwiYSI6ImNqeG9reW0wbzA3ZmwzaHA3ZGRlNGJhY3UifQ.IkI_4dMSNOWgdm7d1ReS6A';
```

Comment: unfortunately this didnt fix my problem

Comment: please look here for an updated question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430738/mapbox-gl-js-external-geojson-data-does-not-load-however-copying-the-geojson-da

Answer (score 1):

Layer type is line but you've set fill paint properties? I would check the docs...

Comment: This didnt solve my problem either. i believe the problem might be that my script cant read geojson files but it works when i copy the geojson data all into the html file. I think im referencing correctly. Let me update my question

Comment: please look here for an updated version of the problem: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57430738/mapbox-gl-js-external-geojson-data-does-not-load-however-copying-the-geojson-da