# Mapbox GL JS external geojson data does not load, however copying the geojson data into the html code works

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

On mapbox GL JS map.addSource(), when pointing the data to an external geojson file (located in the same directory as the html file) the data does not appear. However when I copy the geojson data directly into the html file it does appear. I dont think my pathing is incorrect (trees.geojson is in the same folder as heatmap.html), im using Ubuntu 18.04. **I would like to keep my geojson data external.**

Im trying to follow this tutorial:
https://docs.mapbox.com/help/tutorials/make-a-heatmap-with-mapbox-gl-js/

This does not work:

```html
map.on('load', function() {

  map.addSource('trees', {
    type: 'geojson',
    data: './trees.geojson'
  });
```

This works:

```html
map.on('load', function() {

  map.addSource('trees', {
    type: 'geojson',

    data: {"type":"FeatureCollection","features":[{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":0},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91746,40.44356]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94606,40.44961]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":6},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.96474,40.46283]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.00949,40.42532]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93531,40.42282]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91199,40.37286]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93244,40.43484]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92158,40.43892]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":17},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.97294,40.40908]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":13},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.97291,40.42896]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05708,40.45932]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91069,40.37747]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":4},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.98257,40.43154]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.99177,40.42093]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02488,40.41999]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.99531,40.41504]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":8},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.0148,40.43467]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":6},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02489,40.41446]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01647,40.40107]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":0},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02872,40.39468]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":16},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.00902,40.38418]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":22},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05166,40.43603]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":7},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.0468,40.43461]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.03639,40.44505]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":7},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.03393,40.43546]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":20},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05113,40.43404]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93404,40.47953]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.88148,40.45954]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.9201,40.47591]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":6},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92554,40.46622]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94818,40.4595]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":28},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93549,40.48189]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":23},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.89888,40.42317]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":29},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94479,40.40905]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01717,40.46426]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02638,40.46093]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":22},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93099,40.45362]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92366,40.42568]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.9568,40.44844]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":14},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.9489,40.45985]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91629,40.4733]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":19},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.90083,40.42244]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":2},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.96904,40.44207]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":3},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.00736,40.4574]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93248,40.46246]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93568,40.48163]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":15},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92572,40.46593]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93204,40.46653]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.88447,40.45094]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":19},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92534,40.42169]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":36},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.90062,40.42502]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94987,40.4215]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":8},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94745,40.4583]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91746,40.44368]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94136,40.40568]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":3},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.98904,40.46744]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01252,40.45821]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":15},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.89635,40.43649]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":32},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94086,40.4806]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":20},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92815,40.44201]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":17},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91607,40.42572]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94567,40.40739]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92082,40.45771]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02301,40.45373]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":26},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.90841,40.4471]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93042,40.45842]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":4},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.9858,40.44431]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":7},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01556,40.48392]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":19},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92409,40.42976]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":18},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.90916,40.43699]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":18},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93322,40.43706]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":6},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93512,40.42297]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.94751,40.448]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":5},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.96532,40.46236]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02626,40.46095]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":28},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.89643,40.4709]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":33},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92139,40.43893]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":23},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.93075,40.4537]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":27},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.97275,40.4092]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.97291,40.42903]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":9},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05702,40.45931]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":21},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.91458,40.37661]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":3},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.98257,40.43163]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.99182,40.42098]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":8},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02467,40.42132]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":3},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.99538,40.41503]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":11},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01479,40.43473]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.0249,40.41455]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":8},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.0169,40.40108]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":30},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.02882,40.39472]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":26},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05036,40.43446]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":7},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.04681,40.43454]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":12},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.03631,40.4451]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":19},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.05068,40.43413]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":16},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.95617,40.46891]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":8},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.03394,40.43543]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.88155,40.45938]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":10},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.92019,40.47594]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":-1},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-79.89742,40.46995]}},{"type":"Feature","properties":{"dbh":23},"geometry":{"type":"Point","coordinates":[-80.01727,40.46422]}}]}
  });
```

Comment: Are you running from a local web server?

Comment: Could be a browser restriction, check your browsers console.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your path should probably just be `trees.geojson`, without the `./`. You can get more information by opening the network tab of your debug console. If there is a 404 error, then indeed there is a pathing error.

(In general, Mapbox GL does not support relative paths, so `./` would be wrong.)